# Can't split or rename column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called **en_bal_df** with the following structure:

```
  nrg_bal,siec,unit,geo\time       2018   ...       1991        1990 
0            AFC,BIOE,GWH,AL   3129.617   ...   4221.944    4221.944 
1            AFC,BIOE,GWH,AT  55305.885   ...  27905.111   25744.633 
2            AFC,BIOE,GWH,BA  13379.486   ...          :           : 
3            AFC,BIOE,GWH,BE  27929.856   ...   4108.185    4034.103 
4            AFC,BIOE,GWH,BG  16312.768   ...   1333.333    2005.833
```

The first column is called ***nrg_bal,siec,unit,geo\time***. I would like to split it in four columns using commas as delimiter.

I tried with

```
en_bal_df[['nrg_bal','siec','unit','NUTS-0']]=en_bal_df['nrg_bal,siec,unit,geo\time'].str.split(',',expand=True)
```

but I got the following error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\sand_jv\Desktop\Eurostat Datasets\untitled10.py", line 27, in <module>
    en_bal_df[['nrg_bal','siec','unit','NUTS-0']]=en_bal_df['nrg_bal,siec,unit,geo\time'].str.split(',',expand=True)

  File "C:\Users\sand_jv\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\sand_jv\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 'nrg_bal,siec,unit,geo\time'
```

Then I tried renaming the column with

```
en_bal_df_test=en_bal_df.rename(columns={'nrg_bal,siec,unit,geo\time':'info'},inplace=True)
```

and I didn't get any errors, but nothing happened and the column still has the same name. I think maybe it has to do with the backslash in the name (nrg_bal,siec,unit,geo\time). Any ideas how to solve either of these problems? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas doesn't parse \t as tab in a column name

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'nrg_bal,siec,unit,geo\\time' : [1,2,3]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'nrg_bal,siec,unit,geo\time' : [1,2,3]})
```

Try printing the column name. Depending on the case as below you have to use `\t` or `\\t` while accessing column names:

```
print(df1.columns[0])
```

nrg_bal,siec,unit,geo\time

```
print(df2.columns[0])
```

nrg_bal,siec,unit,geo   ime

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Marcin! I had the idea the problem was in the "geo\time" part, an unfortunate name choice by the Eurostat datasets compiler. I tried adding a second backslash as you mentioned, and now both splitting and renaming the column worked. I modified your code a bit in case someone else may need it:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'nrg_bal,siec,unit,geo\\time' : ['1,a,b,c','2,d,e,f','3,g,h,i']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'nrg_bal,siec,unit,geo\\time' : [1,2,3]})

df1[['nrg_bal','siec','unit','NUTS-0']]=df1['nrg_bal,siec,unit,geo\\time'].str.split(',',expand=True)
df1.drop(columns={'nrg_bal,siec,unit,geo\\time'},inplace=True)

df2.rename(columns={'nrg_bal,siec,unit,geo\\time':'info'},inplace=True)
```

The output is:

```
df1.head()
Out[10]: 
  nrg_bal siec unit NUTS-0
0       1    a    b      c
1       2    d    e      f
2       3    g    h      i

df2.head()
Out[11]: 
   info
0     1
1     2
2     3
```